# Animate grid count with GeoPandas

Tags: python, pandas, animation, geopandas

I'm trying to incorporate the following code into an animation. The data below is a workable example. I'm working with has both date and time as the timestamp.

I'm currently plotting count as a heat map. I'm hoping to use the timestamp column to display the variation of this count over time.

```
gdf_area = gpd.read_file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/master/geojson/limits_IT_municipalities.geojson')#.loc[:, ["geometry"]]

BOXES = 50
a, b, c, d = gdf_area.total_bounds

gdf_grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[
        shapely.geometry.box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
        for minx, maxx in zip(np.linspace(a, c, BOXES), np.linspace(a, c, BOXES)[1:])
        for miny, maxy in zip(np.linspace(b, d, BOXES), np.linspace(b, d, BOXES)[1:])
    ],
    crs="epsg:4326",
)

gdf_grid.insert(0, 'timestamp', range(0, 0 + len(gdf_grid)))

# total area for the grid
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = gdf_grid.total_bounds

# how many cells across and down
n_cells = 30
cell_size = (xmax-xmin)/n_cells

# create the cells in a loop
grid_cells = []
for x0 in np.arange(xmin, xmax+cell_size, cell_size ):
        for y0 in np.arange(ymin, ymax+cell_size, cell_size):
            # bounds
            x1 = x0-cell_size
            y1 = y0+cell_size
            grid_cells.append(shapely.geometry.box(x0, y0, x1, y1))
        
cell = gpd.GeoDataFrame(grid_cells, columns = ['geometry'], crs = 'EPSG:4326')

merged = gpd.sjoin(gdf_grid, cell, how='left', predicate='within')

# make a simple count variable that we can sum
merged['gridCount'] = 1

# Compute stats per grid cell -- aggregate fires to grid cells with dissolve
dissolve = merged.dissolve(by = 'index_right', aggfunc = 'count')

# put this into cell
cell.loc[dissolve.index, 'gridCount'] = dissolve['gridCount'].values

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

im = cell.plot(column = 'gridCount', 
               cmap = 'viridis_r', 
               #vmax = 1000,
               alpha = 0.5,
               edgecolor = 'grey')

def animate(data):

    im.set_data(data)

    return im

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = 10,
                               interval=50)
```

Output:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'set_data'
```

Comment: what's the question? looks like you have working code getting all the way through plotting a single frame of your desired animation... is there somewhere specifically that you're stuck? sorry but "can you finish my project for me" isn't a valid question :)  see the guide to [ask]

Comment: Have you tried looping as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67869792/how-to-use-line-set-data-for-data-that-is-a-2-dimensional-array-in-matplotlib)?

Comment: Thanks. I did try but getting an attribute error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the timestamp, but for the animate function you could call `cell.plot()` with the `ax` parameter set to your `ax`.  The following created a animated gif with randomly generated `gridCount` values. You can adapt this code to generate the `gridCount` values based on the `data` parameter of the `animate` function.

```
from random import randint

import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np
import shapely


gdf_area = gpd.read_file('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openpolis/geojson-italy/master/geojson/limits_IT_municipalities.geojson')

BOXES = 50
a, b, c, d = gdf_area.total_bounds

gdf_grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    geometry=[
        shapely.geometry.box(minx, miny, maxx, maxy)
        for minx, maxx in zip(np.linspace(a, c, BOXES), np.linspace(a, c, BOXES)[1:])
        for miny, maxy in zip(np.linspace(b, d, BOXES), np.linspace(b, d, BOXES)[1:])
    ],
    crs="epsg:4326",
)

# total area for the grid
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = gdf_grid.total_bounds

# how many cells across and down
n_cells = 30
cell_size = (xmax-xmin)/n_cells

# create the cells in a loop
grid_cells = []
for x0 in np.arange(xmin, xmax+cell_size, cell_size ):
        for y0 in np.arange(ymin, ymax+cell_size, cell_size):
            # bounds
            x1 = x0-cell_size
            y1 = y0+cell_size
            grid_cells.append(shapely.geometry.box(x0, y0, x1, y1))
cell = gpd.GeoDataFrame(grid_cells, columns = ['geometry'], crs = 'EPSG:4326')


fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()

def animate(data):
    cell['gridCount'] = [randint(1,10) for _ in range(0, len(cell))] 
    im = cell.plot(
        'gridCount', 
        cmap = 'viridis_r',         
        alpha = 0.5,
        edgecolor = 'grey',
        ax=ax,
    )
    return im

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,  frames = 10, interval=50)
anim.save('map.gif', writer='imagemagick')
```

Output:

[image: random map animation]

Comment: Thanks. This gets me part of the way. I need to include the timestamp though with the initial code

Comment: @jonboy can you give more explanation on what you are trying to accomplish with the timestamp?  In the above code it appears that the timestamp column is all zeros.  This results in a static image because the gridcounts do not change over time.  Are you wanting to bin them into 10 time intervals and then animate the cumulative sum in each bin as you step through time?

Comment: Have you considered using [matplotlib's heatmap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html) support?  This might be a more straight forward way to build the heatmap if you do not need the result to be in a geospatial format.